# Not getting expected value when running a program

Tags: c

```
int a=10;
float b;
printf("the no\n");

b=((10-1)/12)*50;
printf("b value is %f",b);  
return 0;
```

But when I calculate the `b` value in scientific calc we get `b=40`. And my question is why it shows `b=0` when I run my code

Comment: Because  12 is an int

Comment: `int` don't have the fractional part!

Comment: Don't blame yourself. It's just an example of how C takes a well known symbol and redefine its meaning; in C 1/2 equals zero and x = 0 is false even if x is zero.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: but it is pretty much well defined. All integer values are... well .. they are all *integer*.

Answer (score 2):

In the calculation, the expression `((10-1)/12)` is a division of an integer by an integer. The first integer evaluates to `9`, and since `9/12` is less than `1`, `9/12` evaluates to `0`. This `0` is then multiplied by `50` to give `b = 0`.

To make the division act like a float, make one of the constants in the division portion a float. You can do this several ways the shortest of which is to add "f" as a suffix to one of the numbers, e.g. use `10F` instead of `10`, to get `((10F-1)/12)`. This makes the subtraction a floating point operation, which make the division and then multiplication of your original expression floating point operations as well. This should then give you the expected (float) result.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a loss of data when you try to perform integer division. As already explained,

```
b=((10-1)/12)*50;
```

will yield `0` because :

```
((10-1)/12)*50; = (9/12)*50;  =  (0)*50;    =    0;
```

To prevent this data loss, you can do the following:

```
((10-1)/12.0)*50;
```

Basically, by `12.0`, it will be read as a `float`, so appropriately, floating point division will be performed.